# Disable twig functionality

Tags: php, twig

Most companies use Twig as a template engine give clients and users the ability to do some custom templating in their - lets say - views or application. But sometimes you dont want the client to use default functionality like `include` or `block`. Is there a method or way to disable those functionality?

Comment: If you feel adventurous, you could override Twig's default parser or compiler with your own class and have it ignore the tags you don't want. But it's probably easier to run client-made templates through a sort of pre-filter that removes those tags before sending the template to Twig.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is [Twig extension `sandbox`](https://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/2.x/api.html#sandbox-extension). You can define whitelist of tags, filters, methods etc. If user will call something not whitelisted, `Twig_Sandbox_SecurityError` exception will be thrown.